# Removing characteristic rows in a simple Excel file

Tags: python, excel

I need to remove some rows in an simple and straight-forward Excel file.

For example, to remove the rows that column B is not blank.

[image]

What I can think of is not really a ‘remove’ way, but rename a new created file:

```
import os
import xlwt
from xlrd import open_workbook

old_file = open_workbook('C:\\file.xls',formatting_info=True)
old_sheet = old_file.sheet_by_index(0)

new_file = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8', style_compression = 0)
new_sheet = new_file.add_sheet('Sheet1', cell_overwrite_ok = True)

contents = []

for row in range(old_sheet.nrows):
    a = old_sheet.cell(row,0).value
    b = old_sheet.cell(row,1).value
    if len(b) < 1:
        contents.append(a)

for c, content in enumerate(contents):
    new_sheet.write(c, 0, content)


new_file.save('C:\\file_1.xls')

os.remove('C:\\file.xls')
os.rename('C:\\file_1.xls', 'C:\\file.xls')
```

Well, it’s not really deleting the rows but anyhow it could be a suitable way.

What better ways are there to do this, such as considering more conditions?

Comment: You've done it right. see this thread [Python to delete a row in excel spreadsheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635054/python-to-delete-a-row-in-excel-spreadsheet)

Comment: Ultimately, this is what Excel itself does anyway. There is *no such thing* as "modifying" a file "in place". It's just an illusion created by the Excel user interface. If you are in Excel and make a change, and then press Ctrl+S, what it does is blow away the old file, replacing it with a brand-new one that has the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure Python library haven't good solition for work with `xls`. I would decide this problem on two ways:

1. [Use COM interface](http://oreilly.com/catalog/pythonwin32/chapter/ch12.html).
2. Use macro and call `excel` as [external process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050505/way-to-run-excel-macros-from-command-line-or-batch-file).

Also you can consider use `xlsx`, `jython` and `Apache POI`

Answer (score 2):

It's easier to handle when you use csv file instead of xls file.

Answer (score 2):

try `pyexcel`:

```
>>> import pyexcel
>>> r=pyexcel.FilterableReader("mysample.xls")
>>> keep_row_func = lambda row: row[1] == ''
>>> r.filter(pyexcel.filters.RowValueFilter(keep_row_func))
>>> pyexcel.utils.to_array(r)
[111.0, '', 222.0, '', 444.0, '', 666.0, '', 777.0, '']
>>> w=pyexcel.Writer("output.xlsx") # or output.ods, output.csv
>>> w.write_reader(r)
>>> w.close()
```

With `pyexel`, you can use above script over any of these file formats: ods, csv, xls, xlsx and xlsm. Documentation is here: http://pythonhosted.org//pyexcel/