# Delete row/column from Excel with xlsxwriter

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

Is it possible?

I know `ws.set_row('B:B', options={'hidden': True})`

But, is there something like `ws.set_row('B:B', options={'delete_row': True})`?

Answer (score 3):

To quote the [`Worksheet` docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html):

```
"""
The options parameter is a dictionary with the following possible keys:

'hidden'
'level'
'collapsed'
""""
```

Other values like `delete_row` are not acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't seem possible to do what you ask. Probably the best approach remains the one proposed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5635203/9302488) old post.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete a column with XlsxWriter. The best option is to structure your application so it doesn't write data to the column in the first place.